# Wordpress - Remove Version Number From CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, version

I am using a wordpress theme, and the css file uploads with version number:
**style.css?ver=1.2.8**

The problem is that when i change the css file, the browser keep loading the file without my changes. I can see that the changes were saved on the server, but nothing help to load the right file.

I tried:

```
function remove_cssjs_ver( $src ) {
if( strpos( $src, '?ver=' ) )
    $src = remove_query_arg( 'ver', $src );
return $src;
}
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', 'remove_cssjs_ver', 10, 2 );
```

But everything disappeared.

I read the other topics on the subject but nothing helped.

Thank you.

Comment: can you show the code where  you link the style.css file?

Comment: its a ready theme, where can i find it?

Comment: in your theme folder in the file called functions.php

Comment: wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-auth-check' ); its all I found in the functions file.

Comment: you can see it in: http://www.megawpthemes.com/wordpress/realtor/about-2/       see the p style, i changes it in the original file, but it stayed the same...

Comment: did you edit the version which is at the top of your .css file ?

Answer (score 7):

That below given code may help you.

```
function vc_remove_wp_ver_css_js( $src ) {
if ( strpos( $src, 'ver=' . get_bloginfo( 'version' ) ) )
    $src = remove_query_arg( 'ver', $src );
return $src;
}
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', 'vc_remove_wp_ver_css_js', 9999 );
add_filter( 'script_loader_src', 'vc_remove_wp_ver_css_js', 9999 );
```

Taken from https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/132282/removing-wordpress-version-number-from-included-files

That works for me, hope it will work for you as well.

Comment: This does nothing for me. Always loading the old 
style.css?ver=e0a80bacbbe7adc29bd7d945d6748ae8

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to the functions.php of your theme.

```
function remove_file_version($src){
    return preg_replace("/\?ver=[0-9.]+/", "", $src);
}

add_filter('style_loader_src', 'remove_file_version', 100);
add_filter('script_loader_src', 'remove_file_version', 100);
```

Comment: While posting an answer please make a practice of adding some description about your answers